No sign-in screen when accessing my Azure Web App
I published an ASP.NET web app to Azure, but I'm not getting the sign-in screen.
I'm able to call the API and retrieve data when I set the Restrict access option to Allow unauthenticated access. I have followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service?tabs=workforce-configuration#dnl-note which states "You should be directed to a secured sign-in page, verifying that unauthenticated users aren't allowed access to the site." In my case this sign-in page is never shown, instead I just see a blank page with the text "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."
Am I missing or forgetting something?
Minimal reproducible example
Create Web app

Open Visual Studio and then select Create a new project.
In Create a new project, find, and select ASP.NET Core Web API, then select Next.
In Configure your new project, name the application WebAppApi, and then select Next.
Additional information: Framework: .NET 8.0, Authentication type: None, Configure for HTTPS, Do not use top-level statements, Use controllers
Select Create.
Run the application
The browser should now display some data retrieved through the web app.

Create Azure Web App

Go to Azure portal
Go to Web Services
Select Create Web App
Name the Web App "WebAppApi".
Use the settings: runtime stack: .NET 8, Pricing plan: Free F1
Enable basic authentication
Use default settings otherwise and create.
After deployment, go to Download publish profile

Publish web app

Right click the project -> Publish
Import the downloaded publish profile
Press publish
Now you can go to the Default domain link in the overview page of the web app and add "/weatherforecast", you should see the same data as running it in Visual Studio

This works great, except that anyone can access this API. I would like to use Microsoft Authentication to restrict access to just the users within my organization.
Add app authentication to your web app running on Azure App Service
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service?tabs=workforce-configuration#dnl-note

In the Azure Web App go to Settings - Authentication
Add identity provider
Select Microsoft
Select Workforce configuration
Select Create new app registration
Name: WebAppApi
Account type: Current tenant
Allow requests only from this application itself
Allow requests from any identity
Allow requests only from the issuer tenant
Require authentication
HTTP 401 Unauthorized: recommended for APIs
Check Token store box
Select Add

Verify access

Go to the Default domain link in the overview page of the web app and add "/weatherforecast" (same as before)
You will see a message "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." instead of a sign-in page as the guide mentioned

Update
I'm able to get the sign in page by adding the following code to a desktop client application calling the API:
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(<client-app-registration-id>)
    .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, <tenant-id>)
    .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
    .Build();

string[] scopes = [<registered-scope>];

AuthenticationResult result = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

string accessToken = result.AccessToken;

using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(<api-address>);

I created a new app registration for a desktop client which has a permission for a scope defined by the WebAppApi registration.
I checked the token I received and the aud, iss and appid seem correct. Still the HttpResponseMessage is StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'.

I got the authentication working. Thanks to Shiraz Bhaiji's answer I started looking into the token sent by the client. I started implementing my own AuthenticationHandler on the server side to see what was going on. I think one of the issues was that the authentication issuer wasn't matching: the server was expecting login.microsoftonline.com, but the client was sending sts.windows.net.
After some googling I found a fix by changing requestedAccessTokenVersion from "null" to "2" in the App Registration manifest on Azure.

You do not get a sign in page when you have an API project.
The API expects that authentication information is sent in the HTTP header when you make the call.
